# Logstash mysql nested elasticsearch field with delimted field

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, field, delimiter

Have created a query in mysql that creates a category breadcrumb and said field has multiple values. Note 1 row of of the recordset

The following represent the field "categories" from 1 row of the wordpress database This is a hack sql query, open to doing differently):
     "Wall Street Journal:Opion:Letters To The Editor","Wall Street     Journal:Community:Contributions"

```
   Field Mappping is as follows:
   Categories:{
    type:"nested",
    properties:{
    level:{type:"integer"},
    ancestors:{type:"string", index:"not_analyzed"},
    value:{type:"string", index:"not_analyzed"},
    order:{type:"integer"}
```

}
}

Data needs to look like this for ingestion:

```
Categories:[
        {level:1, value:"New York Times", ancestors:[]},
        {level:2, value:"Opinion", ancestors:["New York Times"]},
        {level:3, value:"Letters To The Editor", ancestors:["New York     Times", "Opinion"]},
        {level:2, value:"Community", ancestors:["New York Times"]},
        {level:3, value:"Submissions", ancestors:["New York Times", "Community"]},
]
```

Any suggestions for how I might utilize logsash to loop through the comma separated list and then loop through the fields that use ":".

Thanks for any help. Running both 2.4.4 and 5 Elasticsearch

Comment: Can you show one full record that you extract with your SQL query, or at least a complete view of the `categories` field? Is it a comma-separated field like `"Wall Street Journal:Opion:Letters To The Editor","Wall Street Journal:Community:Contributions"` ?

Comment: @val you are spot on correct. The output of the categories field in mysql field for each row looks like: "Wall Street Journal:Opion:Letters To The Editor","Wall Street Journal:Community:Contributions"